# MySQL - count multiple tables by day

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, union

I have various tables that track stuff being created within the system, sales, customer accounts, etc, and they all have created times on them. I can summarize any one of these on a per day basis with the following query:

```
select date(created_time), count(*) from customers group by date(created_time)
```

Which produces output like:

```
+--------------------+----------+
| date(created_time) | count(*) |
+--------------------+----------+
| 2012-10-12         |       15 |
| 2012-10-13         |        4 |
```

That gets the job done although it does skip over days when nothing happened.

However what I'd like to do is generate the same thing for multiple tables at once, producing something like:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
| date(created_time) | count(sales) | count(customers) |
+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
| 2012-10-12         |           15 |                1 |
| 2012-10-13         |            4 |                3 |
```

I could run the query separately for each table and join them by hand, but the skipping 0 days makes that join difficult.

Is there a way I can do this in a single mysql query?

Comment: Do all the tables have the same structure? Can you do an outer join on date(created_time): select a.date(created_time), a.count(*), b.count(*) from customers a outer join sales b on a.date(created_time) = b.date(created_time) group by a.date(created_time), b.date(created_time). NOTE: using this date() function like this will make for a SLOW query. How much data do you have?

Comment: They all have created_time columns, otherwise they are completely different from each other. The largest one is something like 170,000 rows and growing fast.

Comment: I'm not an expert on query efficiency, but I know that using the date() function as I suggest above will cause slowdowns. Perhaps someone could comment on the efficacy of using a computed column to store the dates?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT created_time, SUM(customers), SUM(sales) 
FROM (SELECT DATE(created_time) created_time, COUNT(*) customers, 0 sales 
      FROM customers 
      GROUP BY created_time 
      UNION 
      SELECT DATE(created_time) created_time, 0 customers, COUNT(*) sales 
      FROM sales 
      GROUP BY created_time
     ) as A
GROUP BY created_time;
```

Comment: You should use `union all` rather than `union`.  It is unnecessary to remove duplicates.

Comment: We can do it but it will depends on what type of query user wants

Comment: No, it has no dependency at all.  The rows are all distinct because of the way that you are pivoting the columns.  Use `union all` instead of `union`.